# Resizing Raspberry Pi image

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I have an 32GB Raspberry Pi image. But the partition size is only 8GB (guess i set it all up on a 8GB SD card some time ago), and I don't need more than 8GB of space.

Now I am going to program a 100 SD cards (all 32GB, they're already bought). It just seem stupid to use a lot of time programming 32GB, when everything above 8GB probably are 0's or garbage.

How can I take my 32GB image and resize it to 10GB (just to be safe)? Can I just delete the last 22GB? and how would I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43211752/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a Python script:

```
infile = open("Raspberry.img", "rb")
outfile = open("NewImage.img", 'wb')
counter = 0; 

try:
    byte = infile.read(1)
    while counter < 10*1000: #10000000000:
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = infile.read(1000000);
        outfile.write(byte);
        counter += 1;
        print(counter)
finally:
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: Please do not add voting commentary or advice to your questions or answers. Put them in the comments if you must, but my experience is they will rarely elicit responses from the voters you wish to speak to.

Comment: (At a guess, your one downvote was made because the question is not strictly about programming - _Super User_ may have been a better place for it).

Comment: I was unable to boot my RPi after doing this.