# osx truncate sd card img

Tags: macos, sd-card, truncate

I have created an image of my sd card containing raspbian using the `dd` tool. This gave me a 16,09 GB big image file. The actual data on there is about 5gb, and I want to truncate it so I can store/clone it onto a 8gb sd card.

All help results I found required Linux to do this (tools like resize2fs doesn't appear to be available for osx, at least, can't find it with homebrew).

What tool(s) can I use to remove the 'empty' space of my .img file?

Answer (score 3):

If you just created it using `dd`, it is just a dump with no filesystem-specific interpretation, so you can just as easily use `dd` to get the first 6GB or so:

```
dd if=Existing16GBimage.img of=New6GBimage.img bs=1m count=6000
```

Comment: It didn't work, still extracted the entier img (32G)

Comment: This worked for me on Linux